# Xcode won't pass arguments to C++ executable

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, command-line-arguments

I'm attempting to debug a C++ project using Xcode. My program looks for input through stdin like so:

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
```

I have an input file called `input.txt` that I normally pass into the executable like so:

```
./verti < input.txt
```

In order to accomplish the same thing while debugging in Xcode, I've added an argument to be passed on launch by Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... > Run > Arguments with a value of `< input.txt`. The text file is located in the same working directory as the executable, yet when I build/run the program, the text file isn't being passed in. The program just waits for input that it should receive. If you guys could lend any insight, that'd be really helpful.

I'm running Xcode 6.3.1 on OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: You probably missed to open that file using a `std::ifstream` and replace `cin` with that variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<` is actually interpreted by the shell (when using a terminal and the command line). In case of Xcode there is no shell involved, so you can't pipe input to `stdin`.

You have to open the file (in `argv[1]`) in your process and use the file descriptor instead of stdin.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can't see that in the question. The OP is clearly trying to use < as an argument (in the Xcode environment) which obviously will not work.

Comment: You are right I misread the part _"... Run > Arguments with a value of < input.txt. "_

Comment: Thanks, you're right! "< input.txt" corresponded to argv[1] and arv[2]. Is there no function in Xcode to pipe to stdin in another way?